# How to customize button's border to make it rounded border?

Tags: css, button, customization

i've tried to customize the button, but it didnt work out a bit. I've seen tutorial to customize the button, but all of the tutorial are using input element, but i'm using button element. Please help

Comment: can you put in what you have tried so far? html + css code ?

Comment: `button{border-radius: some_value}`? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4hhLbdf/1)

Comment: thank you! You helped alot. It changed. The border changed! :))))

Answer (score 1):

```
button {
  border-radius: 5px; // Increase/decrease px
}
```